# Web.config files are not identical on all machines in the farm. SPWebService

Tags: web-services, service-application, health-analyzer

This rule is talking about a difference in **web.configs** between 2 servers in my farm. The failing service is **SPWebService**, so it must be talking about the "SharePoint Web Services" web app in **IIS Manager**.  Other than that, I have all my web apps on one server and only Central Admin on the other.. so it couldn't be talking about one of those.  Could it?

I'm comparing the web.config for "SharePoint Web Services" from both servers.  On the one for the Central Admin server (also hosting service applications), I see several entries for service applications.. which is to be expected.

So there are differences, and I think that's supposed to be like that.  Why is this error coming up in **health analyzer?**  Repair automatically does nothing.. (although why would it).

Other threads I've seen say disable the Repair automatically column?  I don't see how that's a solution.  I did try it though with no change.

Can someone help me understand what's happening here?  Yes, I have read the technet article about the error.  It only tells me to fix differences.. I don't see any that make sense to fix.

The rule also says:

> "0 - Rule Execution Failure" under Severity.

Answer (score 2):

SPWebService is the Foundation Web service (the service that provisions Web Applications/IIS Sites/Application Pools for Web Applications).

Compare your Web Application web.configs between the servers. You can use Notepad++ with the Compare plugin to help with this. Changes to the web.config for Web Applications should be done via the WebConfigModification class. This would typically be done via a SharePoint solution deployed to the farm, but can also be done via [PowerShell script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/c5ff9839-08c7-426b-ade4-9bc19da5377c#content).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my post.  I have ALL my SharePoint web applications being served from one server.  Those web applications do not exist on the other server.  Only Central Admin is there.  There is nothing to compare.  The only common web application between the 2 servers is "SharePoint Web Services"

Comment: SharePoint Web Services is just a place holder for Web Services (e.g. User Profile Service, Managed Metadata Service). You may want to run ulsviewer and re-check the Health Analyzer Rule, see what error comes up in ULS.